# Asserting an exception in ZeroCode for Kafka ACL testing

Tags: apache-kafka, junit, zerocode

I am trying to test a kafka reader writer scenario where the user has permission to write to the topic, but does not have permission to read from that topic.

The java code looks like this :

```
@TargetEnv("kafka_servers/kafka_test_server.properties")
@RunWith(ZeroCodeUnitRunner.class)
public class KafkaConsumeJsonTest {

@Test
@Scenario('path/to/writer-can-write-but-cannot-read.json')
public void test writerWritesButCantRead(){}

}
```

The corresponding JSON looks like this :

```js
{
  "scenarioName": "Writer can write to a topic but cannot read from it",
  "steps": [{
      "name": "write to test topic",
      "url": "kafka-topic:test-topic",
      "operation": "produce",
      "request": {
        "records": [{
          "key": "101",
          "value": "Hello World"
        }]
      },
      "assertions": {
        "status": "Ok",
        "recordMetadata": "$NOT.NULL"
      }
    },

    {
      "name": "onload_kafka",
      "url": "kafka-topic:test-topic",
      "operation": "unload",
      "request": {
        "consumerLocalConfigs": {
         "recordType": "JSON", 
         "maxNoOfRetryPollsOrTimeouts": 3
        }
      },
      "assertions": {
        "status": "Failed",
        "message": "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: my-group"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the test I encounter :

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not
> authorized to access group: my-group.

This is a valid exception and I would to assert that in my test code to prove that the user cannot read from the topic with my-group as gorup-id.

How do I assert this in the test case or in the scenario JSON?

Thanks,
JE

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on zero code github and I got an answer.

**Solution**
We will need to create our own kafka client by extending Kafka Client. In this custom Kafka Client we need to have try catch loop. In the try block delegate the call to super class and in the try block catch exception and return required message.
In our Zero Code test, we need to use the newly created Custom kafka Client.

Here is the full conversation [link](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/issues/508) if someone is interested.